# How do I avoid jsonschema2pojo generating duplicate classes that I already have?

Tags: java, maven, jsonschema2pojo

I have a jsonschema file defining a class that I need as a child class of an already existing POJO (not defined by a schema)

As I found on the jsonschema2pojo documentation, the way to do it is:

```
{
...
"type": "object",
"extends": {
  "type": "object",
  "javaType": "com.example.Document"
},
"properties": { ... }
```

However, when I run maven clean install, the compilation fails because it tries to generate its own Document class (with the `@Json...` annotations and so on) and Maven throws this error

```
error: duplicate class: com.example.Document
```

According to the docs, the plugin shouldn't try to generate a class that already exists. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it by adding the module as a dependency of jsonschema2pojo in the `<plugin>` section of the pom file.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: If I added the module I needed classes generated for, as a dependency of the plugin itself, it recognized them better

Answer (score 1):

Is the already "existing" class just a source file? If it is just a java source file which will be compiled as part of your mvn clean install process, then the plugin can't infer the existence of this class. If this class is already compiled and has been added as a dependency to your mvn pom, then the plugin should skip creation of a duplicate class.

Comment: It's a previously-writen source file, yes. I have added the module to the jsonschema2pojo plugin dependencies. And now the plugin recognizes the classes in the classpath and doesn't try to generate new ones. Is there a better way to specify these dependencies? Any negative side effects of doing this?

Comment: This is great.  Was so hard to find!

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me in version `1.0.0-beta1`:

```
...
  "extends": {
    "type": "object",
    "existingJavaType": "io.radanalytics.operator.common.EntityInfo"
  },
...
```

No need to modify the `pom.xml`